# Android application with more than one screen

Tags: java, android, authentication, screen

I'm currently trying to develop an android application in eclipse(java) which shows some jokes downloaded from a database. The user is able to vote on each joke once, and to make sure they only do that once, I have made a table in the database that contains three columns.

- E-mail
- Username (Used when a user publishes a joke)
- Encrypted Password

I have two "screens" right now:

- Login screen
- Main screen

At every single start up the application checks the SharedPreferences for a file containing some information, and if there is some information it should load the Main screen, but if there is no account information the  Login screen should be loaded.

Any idea on how I can use different screens, and how should it be coded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. In your `Activity`, check if there is account info. If there isn't then `setContentView` to the Log in screen. Otherwise, `setContentView` to your other content. If you go this route, you'll have to have the logic of both the login `Activity` and the other in the same Activity. Shouldn't be too bad if the logic is relatively uncomplicated.
2. Have two activities. The default Activity can be the login `Activity`, but in `onCreate()` you can check if the info already exists and if it does, simply start the other `Activity` right away and return from `onCreate()`. Otherwise, continue with `setContentView`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will number 1 for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single top layout (e.g. FrameLayout) that contains two overlapping layouts (one for the login and one for the main). Use a single activity. When the activity starts do setContentView() to the top layout. Then define a method selectScreen(boolean isMain) that based on the argument sets the main layout on and the login off (or vice versa). You turn screens on/off using the setVisibility() method in class View. You can switch screen any time by calling that method. If you want to be extra fancy you can use standard animations when flipping screens.